# If I choose to use a naked domain for my website (no www), will I be unable to use a CDN later?

Tags: seo, domains, cdn

I would like to use a naked domain instead of one with a sub domain but am worried about some potential issues down the line.

It is an ecommerce site so if the site grows then a content delivery network (CDN) will most likely be used. I believe you cant use a CNAME on a root domain. Would the best solution be to use a separate external domain e.g. staticexample.com? If we did use an external domain, would that affect images in search results?

Comment: You can use a CNAME to alias a domain name to a providers sub-domain. People do this all day every day. No worries. Cheers!!

Comment: Using an external domain does not affect your image SERPS and in fact, most companies don't brand their CDNS and just use the ones provided by their CDN provider.

Comment: Ok thanks. So from what I've researched the only disadvantage of having a "naked" domain would be that cookies get sent to all sub domains, we're not planing on using a sub domain so this isn't an issue. Is there anything else i should be aware of?

Comment: @closetnoc a CNAME can not exist at apex of zone, hence for the "naked" domain. This is per DNS specifications. Various providers offer various workarounds for that.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek Not trying to snotty. Honest. My statement was simple. A CNAME can be used to alias a domain name to a providers sub-domain. This is not only factual, but something I did automatically as a part of my hosting business daily for decades. I was one the the first registered ISPs, web hosts, represented U.S. Robtics at ISPONE, was a core network consultant to all the major telecoms and backbone providers, etc. My simple statement is indeed factual. I, however, am not sure what you are trying to say. (Said with kindness.) Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc and still you can not put a CNAME record at apex of your zone. You can put in it something that will look and work like it, but it is not a CNAME record per the DNS specifications. It may be called like that to pass the idea but it is not the technical definition of a CNAME. Like I said various providers provide various workarounds or look-alike for that, this is nothing new nor magic. And there are a lot of proposals to handle that case. What I am trying to say, sorry for my poor English if not clear, is just a rehash of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20230670  or numerous others...

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I will poke around. Keep in mind that I created my zones via simple codei wrote myself. Bare in mind that initially there were no control panels or APIs or even solutions for creating some files other than an editor. I wrote C code for this as recently as just 3 years ago for self defending networks. I will go back and refresh my memory and study your link in a few. Cheers mate!!

Comment: @closetnoc I am quite hopeful that you did not create a DNS server but used one already existing, like `bind`. Try to put a CNAME at apex in a zonefile and load it with `bind`... you will see the result (an error). I am sure you have found out at that time another way to do the same thing.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have always used bind. How I did it, I will have to find old code. I still have nearly 90 of my old servers sitting around to play with. I still use a cobalt for an internal dns. Perhaps I will play with that or my test server if I find the newer code. I just have to see how I did it. It was common to point a domain name to a sub-domain of my own domain to service fail over dynamically. It was one of several methods. This would happen in the blink of an eye automatically.

Comment: @closetnoc Pointing the apex domain as a A of a sub-domain can only be done if you fully control the DNS server and likely have a slightly modified one that makes allowances or this (i.e. make it appear to be an A record when its actually delegating to another sub-domain). There is no "externally visible" way to CNAME the apex... So if you have it working it's in some way custom or perhaps there is misunderstanding about what

Answer (score 1):

You can either use an external domain or subdomain of your main domain with the same results. The only think you have to take into account is that they must be **cookieless** and **fast** in order to work propertly as your own CDN.

In the future you will be able to switch easily to a professional CDN in both situations.